# PyInstaller: FileNotFoundError when trying to run the distribution file

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm helping out a friend who needs to transform some data in csvs, so I made a little python program called "csv_converter.py"- it takes a csv input file and csv output file and everything's peachy.

I want to be able to give them a file they can run on their machine (without necessarily needing python and pandas) so I'm trying PyInstaller. 
In the directory with my python program I run: `pyinstaller csv_converter.py`

According to the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html), it'll make a 'dist' folder where "you find the bundled app you distribute to your users." It sounds like the key file to run will be: dist/csv_converter/csv_converter (clarification source: [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4902)), and then I can either send the whole csv_converter folder, or just the csv_converter file if I run the Pyinstaller command with the --onefile argument.

After running PyInstaller I see these directories created, but when I navigate to dist/csv_converter/ and try to run that important csv_converter file (before trying to send anything), it's giving the following error:

```
Dianes-MacBook-Pro:csv_converter dkaplan$ ./csv_converter -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth__tkinter.py", line 30, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory "/Users/dkaplan/PycharmProjects/chris_csv_converter/src/dist/csv_converter/tcl" not found.
[36637] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter
```

So close, but so far!  **Has anyone else had this issue or know a workaround?**

Answer (score 1):

I heard back from the kind folks at PyInstaller, and this is a common one they see with tinter. I'm not sure where it was being pulled in from, but the workaround was to exclude it with this argument: --exclude-module=tkinter

I had chosen to use the --onefile argument (slower, but means I can send just one file), so the full command was: `pyinstaller --onefile --exclude-module=tkinter csv_converter.py`

Then:

- I could go to the dist folder and do a test run with: ./csv_converter -h
- then I send that csv_converter file to my friend and he'll be able to run it the same way (without needing python)